# Which file stores the default reboot message broadcast?

Tags: reboot, etc, unattended-upgrades

I use auto security update on my server. Afterwards, the server reboots because I use:

```
Unattended-Upgrade: Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

Naturally, a reboot message is automatically sends to users who are logged on.

So I don't need a answer like "use `shutdown -h+10 "your message ..."`"

I'm looking for the file in `/etc` which stores the default reboot message broadcast.

Comment: I believe it depends on the version of Ubuntu, earlier versions the message is part of the binary.  I don't know where it comes from in the newer versions, doesn't appear to be in the binary though.

Answer (score 1):

The default shutdown message is hard coded in `/lib/systemd/systemd-logind`. If you want to broadcast a different message then you must adopt a different strategy; for example, you may want to look periodically for `/var/run/reboot-required`. See *[How does Ubuntu keep track of the “System restart required” flag in motd](https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd)* on ServerFault.

Comment: It's not what I want to do . I want to change the message :  "Message de diffusion de root@testclone
 (unknown) à 16:00...

The system is going down for reboot in 660 minutes!"

Comment: The default message is hard coded in `/lib/systemd/systemd-logind`. You cannot change it. I have suggested a workaround, namely, instead of using automatic reboot (which will use the hard coded default message), look for `/var/run/reboot-required` and if found issue a reboot request with your customized message.